# How to connect VectorWise Database to Azure Data Factory or Azure Synapse?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, vectorwise

I have a vectorwise database that contain big size multiple table, I need to copy those table into Azure Storage or Azure SQL DB or Synapse. We don't have direct connector for vectorWise in Azure data factory.
Is there any way to connect with VectorWise in ADF by creating API or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to setup a virtual machine on a network which can reach your database, you will need to install the [self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory&WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-4020762) on it, you will need to install the proper ODBC driver from your database vendor, and then create an [ODBC linked service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-odbc?tabs=data-factory&WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-4020762).